# How to implement a purge os soft-deleted records in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In my Postgres 9.4 database, I have the following trigger / function, which implements a "soft-delete" functionality:

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table
ADD COLUMN delete_ind integer


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_mytable_soft_delete()  
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
      command text := ' SET delete_ind = 1 WHERE uuid_col = $1';
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE "my_schema"."my_table"' || TG_TABLE_NAME || command USING OLD.uuid_col;
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER my_table_soft_delete_trigger  
  BEFORE DELETE ON "my_schema"."my_table"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_mytable_soft_delete();
```

The code above gives me the "soft-delete" functionality, but, it also prevents me from actually deleting / purging those rows, which are already marked as deleted.

The new desired behavior, is to have this delete function to examine the value of the delete_ind field, and, if it is already set to 1, to actually purge that row for good.

What is the correct conditional syntax, which would either set the value of delete_ind. or actually delete the row in question, based on the current value of the delete_ind column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a relatively minor modification to your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_mytable_soft_delete()  
RETURNS trigger AS
$$  
BEGIN
    if OLD.delete_ind = 1 then
        /* Delete proceeds, you just needs to *do nothing* 
           except for returning the OLD row as it were */
        RETURN OLD ;  
    else
        /* instead of deleting, set a flag */
        UPDATE my_schema.my_table 
           SET deleted_ind = 1
         WHERE uuid_col = old.uuid_col ;

        /* This will skip the process of this row.
           It will also avoid subsequent triggers to be fired, and the row will
           not be counted on the rows-affected count. If more triggers need
           to be processed, make sure this is the last in the chain.
        */
        RETURN NULL ;
    end if ;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(If your function is used one by one table, you can hard-code it, and don't need Dynamic SQL)

---

*Side note*: If the column `delete_ind` will only be used as a **flag**, its meaning would be best conveyed by declaring it as `boolean not null` instead of `integer`.